# Apply padding to display: table-cell element

Tags: html, padding, css-tables

I'm trying to apply padding to the left side of an element with display:table-cell.  I am using a Webkit browser, and this will only ever have to work in a Webkit browser (yay!).

It displays in the proper arrangement, but as if there is no padding at all.

Any pointers?  I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to `display:table`

Here is my HTML (I've embedded css inline so that it's easier to read here):

```
<div class="setting-group" style="display:table">
   <div class="title">Title</div>
   <div class="field" style="display:table-row">
      <span class="label" style="display:table-cell">Label</span>
      <select class="value" style="display:table-cell; padding-left: 20px" id="id">
         <option value="Opt 1">Option 1</option>
         ...
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your select in a span:

```
<span class="select" style="display:table-cell; padding-left:20px"><select class="value"  id="id"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the property...

```
border-spacing:10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school style, maybe?

```
    .setting-group {
        padding-left:50px;
    }

    .setting-group .field .label {
        padding-right:20px;
    }
```